# How do you know if syslog-ng stops your listening daemon?

Tags: php, linux, syslog, syslog-ng

I wrote a PHP program that hooks into `syslog-ng` (via `syslog-ng.conf`) and it's basically this:

```
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    $input = fgets(STDIN);
    process($input);
}
cleanup();
```

where `process()` and `cleanup()` are defined by me.

The problem I am facing is that `cleanup(2)` is never called and I need it to be executed before the program exits.

I have tried to catch SIGTERM, SIGHUP and SIGPIPE using `pcntl_signal()` and that part of the application seems to work fine (if I use kill -1 on the PHP process, my signal handler gets called and it runs `cleanup()`), but it appears that I am not getting those meessages from syslog-ng.

I have tried setting STDIN to non-blocking, thinking that PHP wouldn't call the signal handlers because the stream was blocking. That didn't work either, my signal handlers wouldn't get called.

How do I know when syslog-ng is about to stop my application, so I can do some cleanup?

Thanks,
Tom

**UPDATE:** I've tried to catch all the signals, from 1 to 31 and it still doesn't receive anything when syslog-ng is restarted (or killed with SIGTERM).

Comment: Retagged, this is not related to signal-processing (not related to signal processing field, related to handling OS signals).

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but have you tried registering cleanup as a shutdown function? http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php

Comment: Edited Tom. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps try to register `cleanup()` as a PHP [shutdown function](http://php.net/register_shutdown), like so:

```
function cleanup(){}
register_shutdown_function("cleanup");
```

In theory this will cause php to execute the function prior to exiting. This may not work when used with forced halt options (like kill) though, so it's (yet another) shot in the dark.

I hope you find something that works though. I'd be interested in learning the results as well.

**Edit: I'm glad this worked out for you!**

Comment: I think you mean `register_shutdown_function('cleanup');`

This is a cool function, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I accidentally downvoted you. Sorry, your answer was correct. Try editing it, so I may reverse the vote.

Comment: Please look at the date on this answer. I no longer work with php and it has change a lot over the years. Please feel free to submit an edit to the answer that meets today's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but try re-writing your loop as follows:

```
do {
   $input = fgets(STDIN);
   process( $input );
while ( !feof( STDIN ) ) {
cleanup();
```

The idea being that when syslog-ng closes stdout (assuming it does?), fgets will attempt to read and actually reach EOF.

Comment: In the case mentioned, wouldn't your logic better suited in a do{ }while() ?

Comment: I would probably add an if around the fgets call as well, since fgets returns false on failure `if( ( $input = fgets(STDIN); ) === FALSE ) break;`

Comment: feof should not be used in a do/while, as feof needs to be checked *before* one reads from a file. Empty files are at EOF upon fopen.

    $ touch testfile
    $ ls -l testfile
    -rw-r--r--  1 clint  staff  0 Nov  9 08:43 testfile
    $ php -r '$x = fopen("testfile", "r"); var_dump($x); $y = feof($x); var_dump($y);'
    resource(5) of type (stream)
    bool(false)

Comment: This is true, however fgets should return false in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

Abrupt termination of your PHP script without proper cleanup is probably because a runtime error happens (for example, because your process() is not ready to handle an empty string returned by by fgets() when it reaches EOF).

Enable PHP error logging to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of things you can try to troubleshoot this:

1) Make use of PHP's [set_error_handler() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

2) Put the code mentioned above in a try/catch structure, to try and catch any exceptions that might be thrown.

3) When you run that script, make sure you are capturing both the output and standard error.  Change the command line to be something like:

`/path/to/script 2>&1 >> /path/to/logfile.txt`

...that will help you catch errors.

Finally, if it really is a case where PHP isn't able to catch signals, you'll have to do this through a shell script with the trap command.  Something like:

`#!/bin/sh

 #

 # This gets run when the script is hit with a signal

 #

trap /path/to/script --cleanup

 #

 # Run our script

 #

/path/to/script 2>&1 >> /path/to/logfile.txt`

If there's specific data in the script that cleanup() needs, then you'll have to see about serializing the data and writing it to disk for the cleanup script to read.

Good luck!

Comment: That still doesn't help when dealing with SIGTERM, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Does PHP thoughtfully handle your signals for you?  Try prototyping in another language that you have more control.