# Using a PHP script as syslog-ng program() destination

Tags: php, syslog-ng

I want to send log entries from syslog-ng to a php script.  Looking at this question: [How do you know if syslog-ng stops your listening daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651532/how-do-you-know-if-syslog-ng-stops-your-listening-daemon) I tried to use the loop described in it:

```
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    $input = fgets(STDIN);
    // do something with $input
}
```

Unfortunately I get the dreaded "POLLERR occurred while idle; fd='20'" message dozens of times a second from syslog-ng. Apparently this means that the script closed its stdin, but obviously my script is not doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `php.ini` sets `max_execution_time` to 0 for your CLI environment. Otherwise your script will be killed and stream closed by PHP Double check you edit right `php.ini` as most distros uses separate config files for each "type" of PHP (CLI/CGI/mod_php).

Comment: No luck. I put php -n nameofscript in syslog.conf so it won't load any ini files, then put all the ini_sets and set_time_limit() in the script (although php docs says there is no max execution time or time limit for command line). Still getting POLLERR occured.